# Can't process links upto certain portion

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I parse links upto the first single forward slash `/` and discard the rest?

list of links:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_processing_captcha.htm
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
```

Expected output:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
https://docs.python.org/
```

I've tried:

```
linklist = [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/",
    "https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/",
    "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_processing_captcha.htm",
    "https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html"
]

for link in linklist:
    custom_link = link.split("/")[0]
    print(custom_link)
```

This gives me:

```
https:
https:
https:
https:
```

> How can I get the desired portion of links?

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm not sure how detecting if a URL is valid or not is relevant to simply extracting one part of a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two forward slashes after `http://`; therefore, you need to get the join the first three elements of the `split`:

```
linklist = [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/",
    "https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/",
    "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_processing_captcha.htm",
    "https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html"
]

for link in linklist:
    custom_link = '/'.join(link.split("/")[:3]) + '/'
    print(custom_link)
```

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/
https://docs.python.org/
```

For more complex operations, you should look into [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).